# Is there a way to sleep your mac through iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, remote-control

In the remote that comes with Apple TV, if you pair it with a mac, you'd be able to press and hold the play/pause button and your mac will go to sleep. Is there a way to do the same with iPhone/iPad Remote app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not out of the box, but there might be an app for that. What I would recommend is simply installing a VNC app on both devices - something like TeamViewer or LogMeIn. Then, you can  use your iPhone to navigate the system menu like you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the sleep/wake function, you may want to take a look at [iNet WOL](http://itunes.apple.com/app/inet-wol-wake-on-lan/id318696675?mt=8#), which does a great job. It's the little brother of [iNet Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inet-pro-network-scanner/id305242949?mt=8), a much more extensive network tool for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Screens](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screens-vnc-client-for-ios/id400012962?mt=8) and [Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) to manage my macs remotely (whether it's the couch or from afar).

The little command `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to sleep'` can be mapped to a function key or alias in your shell and will sleep the mac no matter how it gets called.

Screens: Using the mouse itself requires no setup or you could customize a gesture to activate a Function key that calls the script to automate things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search different alternatives on the iTunes Store. I've used [jfcontrol](http://www.digitalsirup.com/jfcontrol/) in the past with great success. Not the prettiest application, but it deliver. You need a small (very small) server installed on the machine (it's just a little app that runs on the Menu Bar). Pretty much all these apps need a small server.

Comment: I have too many apps in my menu bar already, was avoiding to add another one...

Comment: Yeah, me too, but to be honest, I don't run the server at all times, only when I know I will need to. I.e.: if I'm going to watch a movie or something, then I simply load the daemon. It's instant and since I use launchbar, its probably 5 keystrokes away (no joke). ;)